# Haskell: cross product of a list with subsequences of another list

Tags: list, haskell

I have another question regarding generating lists of stuff from various sources.

UPDATED: Simplified the example

I have a list of variables

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

and bool values

```
[False, True].
```

Now I want to have a list with all subsequences of the variables list crossed with the values list so for each entry the list of subsequences of the variables has, a set of pairs with each of the possible values.

For the lists above I'd get this (complete list for this scenario). As the empty list won't pair with the other list too well, I don't care whether it is part of the result list or not (can be added later easily).

```
[
    [], 
    [("a", False)], 
    [("a", True)], 
    [("b", False)], 
    [("b", True)], 
    [("c", False)], 
    [("c", True)],
    [("a", False), ("b", False)],
    [("a", False), ("b", True)],
    [("a", True), ("b", False)],
    [("a", True), ("b", True)],
    [("a", False), ("c", False)],
    [("a", False), ("c", True)],
    [("a", True), ("c", False)],
    [("a", True), ("c", True)],
    [("b", False), ("c", False)],
    [("b", False), ("c", True)],
    [("b", True), ("c", False)],
    [("b", True), ("c", True)],
    [("a", False), ("b", False), ("c", False)],
    [("a", False), ("b", False), ("c", True)],
    [("a", False), ("b", True), ("c", False)],
    [("a", False), ("b", True), ("c", True)],
    [("a", True), ("b", False), ("c", False)],
    [("a", True), ("b", False), ("c", True)],
    [("a", True), ("b", True), ("c", False)],
    [("a", True), ("b", True), ("c", True)],
]
```

If it was permutations only, a call to permutations combined with a comprehension would suffice, but I have no idea how to get the list for the subseqences easily.
I could do with using the "call to permutations + comprehension"-approach on the lists with different sizes but that doesn't sound very elegant.

Is there a straightfoward solution to that?

Comment: I don't understand what the goal is. Something like `[map (\x -> (x, y)) xs | xs <- subsequences "abcde", y <- tristates]` might be close, but it won't have that interim entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solution :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
solution variables values = do
  as <- subsequences variables
  bs <- forM as $ const values
  zip as bs
```

And to demonstrate that it works:

```
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude> :{
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude| let solution :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude|     solution variables values = do
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude|       as <- subsequences variables
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude|       bs <- forM as $ const values
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude|       return $ zip as bs
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude| :}
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude> solution [ "a", "b", "c" ] [ False, True ]
[[],[("a",False)],[("a",True)],[("b",False)],[("b",True)],[("a",False),("b",False)],[("a",False),("b",True)],[("a",True),("b",False)],[("a",True),("b",True)],[("c",False)],[("c",True)],[("a",False),("c",False)],[("a",False),("c",True)],[("a",True),("c",False)],[("a",True),("c",True)],[("b",False),("c",False)],[("b",False),("c",True)],[("b",True),("c",False)],[("b",True),("c",True)],[("a",False),("b",False),("c",False)],[("a",False),("b",False),("c",True)],[("a",False),("b",True),("c",False)],[("a",False),("b",True),("c",True)],[("a",True),("b",False),("c",False)],[("a",True),("b",False),("c",True)],[("a",True),("b",True),("c",False)],[("a",True),("b",True),("c",True)]]
Data.List Control.Monad Prelude> forM_ it print
[]
[("a",False)]
[("a",True)]
[("b",False)]
[("b",True)]
[("a",False),("b",False)]
[("a",False),("b",True)]
[("a",True),("b",False)]
[("a",True),("b",True)]
[("c",False)]
[("c",True)]
[("a",False),("c",False)]
[("a",False),("c",True)]
[("a",True),("c",False)]
[("a",True),("c",True)]
[("b",False),("c",False)]
[("b",False),("c",True)]
[("b",True),("c",False)]
[("b",True),("c",True)]
[("a",False),("b",False),("c",False)]
[("a",False),("b",False),("c",True)]
[("a",False),("b",True),("c",False)]
[("a",False),("b",True),("c",True)]
[("a",True),("b",False),("c",False)]
[("a",True),("b",False),("c",True)]
[("a",True),("b",True),("c",False)]
[("a",True),("b",True),("c",True)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Control.Monad (forM)
import Data.List (subsequences)

solution :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
solution variables values = do
    sequence <- subsequences variables
    forM sequence $ \variable -> do
        value <- values
        return (variable, value)
```

Proof that it works:

```
>>> mapM_ print $ solution ["a", "b", "c"] [False, True]
[]
[("a",False)]
[("a",True)]
[("b",False)]
[("b",True)]
[("a",False),("b",False)]
[("a",False),("b",True)]
[("a",True),("b",False)]
[("a",True),("b",True)]
[("c",False)]
[("c",True)]
[("a",False),("c",False)]
[("a",False),("c",True)]
[("a",True),("c",False)]
[("a",True),("c",True)]
[("b",False),("c",False)]
[("b",False),("c",True)]
[("b",True),("c",False)]
[("b",True),("c",True)]
[("a",False),("b",False),("c",False)]
[("a",False),("b",False),("c",True)]
[("a",False),("b",True),("c",False)]
[("a",False),("b",True),("c",True)]
[("a",True),("b",False),("c",False)]
[("a",True),("b",False),("c",True)]
[("a",True),("b",True),("c",False)]
[("a",True),("b",True),("c",True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to generate all subsequences of a given list (without thinking about performance) is:

```
subs :: [a] -> [[a]]
subs []      =  [[]]
subs (x:xs)  =  subs xs ++ map (x:) (subs xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to use monads here. The following might be a bit intimidating at first, but I will explain afterwards. Note: Mapping and folding helps the compiler make code faster.

```
solution :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
solution variables values = foldr (<*>) [[]]
  $ map (\variable -> id : map (\value -> (:) (variable, value) ) values)
  $ variables
```

It needs `Control.Applicative`.

The idea is to have picking the subsequence and assigning all possible values as a single process. The function `(\value -> (:) (variable, value) ) :: b -> [(a,b)]->[(a,b)]` takes one value, makes a pair with a variable and produces a function appending this pair to a list of variable-value-pairs.

By mapping this over the list of all values, we get a list of functions `map (\value -> (:) (variable, value) ) values :: [[(a,b)]->[(a,b)]]`. The outer list brackets are for nondeterminism and the inner for the list of bindings.

We add a further option: Not assigning a value. This is done by `id :: [(a,b)]->[(a,b)]`, which is added to the list of possibilities.

The next lambda-abstraction-and-map construction takes the different variables into account: We want to have a list of possible changes for every variable.

```
map (\variable -> (id : map (\value -> (:) (variable, value) ) values)) variables
```

has type `[[[(a,b)]->[(a,b)]]]` where the outer-most list is for variables that are to be bound, the middle layer for nondeterminism and the inner list for variables already bound.

Then comes the big finally: Folding! The fold works on the outer-most list layer (for every variable do something) and this level of list-ness disappears. The `(<*>)` combines all the nondeterminism, which was the middle layer of lists before and is the outer layer of the result. The inner layer is unaffected. The starting value of the fold is `[[]]::[[(a,b)]]`.

If you get used to the `Alternative` interface for nondeterminism you might prefer

```
solution :: Alternative f => [a] -> f b -> f[(a, b)]
solution variables values = foldr (<*>) (pure [])
  $ map (\variable -> pure id <|> pure (\value -> (:) (variable, value)) <*> values)
  $ variables
```

because now the list operations `(:)` and `map` are for the list of variables while everything concerning nondeterminism is handled by the applicative/ alternative interface.